# Symfony2 best way to organise controllers (controller names)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to establish the most logical way to use controllers in Symfony. What are the recommended conventions?

In other frameworks I have previously created a controller related to each model. e.g. If there's a User model, a UserController will handle things related to users, such as login, logout, etc. I don't know if this is the best way of organising an application, and if it applies in the same way to Symfony.

1. When should I create a new controller? For what purpose?

   - Have a controller handling requests related to each entity?
   - Have a controller for each 'section' of a website, based on route names (URLs)?
   - Just use the DefaultController for a bundle and put all actions in there, and use a routing prefix for the whole bundle.
2. Does a bundle need to have a DefaultController?
3. When would I use the DefaultController over my own controller (or vice versa)?

---

An example. I have `AppBundle` and `AdminBundle`. Both will have their own login systems (you can log in to the 'front-facing' site, or log in as an administrator to the admin section).

Imagine I have the following example routes:

**Normal Users (AppBundle)**

```
/                 (home page)
/login            (normal user login)
/directions       (feature 1)
/menu             (feature 2)
/menu/comments    (a sub-section of feature 2)
```

**Administrators (AdminBundle)**

```
/admin                  (administrator home page)
/admin/login            (admin login)
/admin/users            (view registered users)
/admin/users/345/edit   (edit user with ID 345)
```

What would be the best way to organise my controllers here? How many controllers would I need and what convention would I be following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need DefaultController.
I think creating a controller to manage the entity is a good idea. Other practice is "one feature - one controller".

From best practices:

> there's no technical reason for putting business logic inside of a bundle.

So if you have one entity for two bundles (ex. User) you can put it directly in `src/Entity/User.php`.